# How to structure Service and Business Layer with Entity Framework, Repository, Unit of Work and Transactions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactionscope, unit-of-work, service-layer

I have a service layer which makes requests of business layers to perform some functions. 
The business layers access a repository which uses Entity Framework.
The service layer has a Unit Of Work object that maintains references to the ObjectContexts of EF.
When the business layers have been called, the service layer tells the Unit of Work to save the changes which it does inside of a transaction.

This is all working fine, I'm able to have multiple repositories talking to multiple edmx files all in a transaction.

One of the rules in the system is that the EF stuff has to stay the repository layer (apart from the Contexts in the UoW).

But my design has a major flaw.

In a function in the business layer I want to call a respository function to create a new record in the database. Then, in the same function in the business layer, i want to point another record at the new record. The EF entity isn't available to the business layer and because it hasn't returned to the service layer yet I don't have an id for the new record which I could then update the other record with.

Any suggestions on how I should change my design to support this?

Comment: Yes @user2070034. I was able to call SaveChanges() on the context within the repository and then access the newly created uniqueId of the EF entity. I can then use this within the same UoW and either call Commit or Abort on the Transaction to make it permanent.

Comment: any source code sample about in gist , github?